# Does Fiddler's QuickExec support logic operator?

Tags: fiddler

I want to input the following command in QuickExec(e.g., using logic operator 'and'）

> =404 and ?/path/

Namely, the sessions which response
status equal to 404 and the keyword '/path/' appears in URL will be selected in Fiddler.

Does anyone know how to implement/support these operators in Fiddler?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, logical operators aren't supported today. It's a fun idea though and the base case (`=404 /partialpath`) is something I'll probably build in soon.